# Set page title according to dir name

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to set page title on a bunch of old pages.

Initially started as setting the title according to the directory name. I used:

```
<title><?php echo basename(__DIR__); ?></title>
```

... which worked perfectly. Then I wanted to strip hyphens in the dir name from being displayed in the page title. Have tried various different ways but can't put together something that works - probably more a case of not knowing how to combine functions together. This is what I currently have:

```
<title><?php str_replace('_', ' ', basename(__DIR__)); ?></title>
```

Is anyone able to offer suggestions please? I'm a coding newbie so be gentle! Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the result of your current code and the result that you expect.

Comment: currently, with the above code, the result is displaying as the page url only:

http://www.website.com/this-directory

whereas I want the page title to to be:

this directory

Comment: Ok, please add the two examples to your question (not via comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code for my own project to get title according to the current parent directory where the file is located:

```
function getTitle($t){
    $title = basename($t);
    $title = str_replace('_', ' ', $title);//replacing '_' by spaces
    return $title;
}
```

Now call this function from any file passing `__DIR__` as its parameter.

```
<title><?php echo getTitle(__DIR__); ?></title>
```